# JQuery: toggle Q&A class with plus and minus icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle plus and minus span and also toggle the answer div all at once and its not working out.
I built the html so the question div has two childrens:

1. div icons with two children of plus and minus icons
2. div for the answer

this is the code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".question").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".icons div").toggle();
   $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();        
 });
});
```

```css
.question div{
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question .icons .MinusIcon{
  display: none;
}
.answer{
  display:none;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!---------------1--------------->
  <div class="question">
   <div class="icons">
    <div class="plusIcon">[<span>+</span>]</div>
    <div class="MinusIcon">[<span>-</span>]</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Question<br>Question
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
   ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER
  </div>
  <!---------------2--------------->
  <div class="question">
   <div class="icons">
    <div class="plusIcon">[<span>+</span>]</div>
    <div class="MinusIcon">[<span>-</span>]</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Question<br>Question
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
   ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".question").click(function(){            

                $(this).find(".plusIcon").toggle();
                $(this).find(".MinusIcon").toggle();    
                $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Function

```
$(this).find(".icons div.plusIcon").toggle();
$(this).find(".icons div.MinusIcon").toggle();
```

---

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".question").click(function(){
       $(this).find(".icons div.plusIcon").toggle();
$(this).find(".icons div.MinusIcon").toggle();
       $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();        
      });
 
   });
```

```css
.question div{
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question .icons .MinusIcon{
  display: none;
}
.answer{
  display:none;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!---------------1--------------->
  <div class="question">
   <div class="icons">
    <div class="plusIcon">[<span>+</span>]</div>
    <div class="MinusIcon">[<span>-</span>]</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Question<br>Question
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
   ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER
  </div>
  <!---------------2--------------->
  <div class="question">
   <div class="icons">
    <div class="plusIcon">[<span>+</span>]</div>
    <div class="MinusIcon">[<span>-</span>]</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Question<br>Question
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
   ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER<br> ANSWER
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve toggling the +/- icons along with the answers div by doing the following in your code:

1. Use a single div with just the plusIcon

   `<div class="icons">
       <div class="plusIcon"></div>
   </div>`
2. Toggle the minusIcon class on click using:

   `$(this).find(".icons div").toggleClass("minusIcon");`

The + & - icons are provided by pseudo elements from CSS:

```
.plusIcon:before {
  content: "[+]";
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
.minusIcon:before {
 content: "[-]";
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
}
```

You can find the complete solution here http://jsfiddle.net/d1cot84e/1/

Answer (score 0):

With little modifications in OP's code, here's how it looks:

```js
  $(".question").on('click', function() {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
    var visible = $answer.is(':visible');
    $(this).children('.icons').text(visible ? '[+]' : '[-]');
    $answer.slideToggle();
  });
```

```css
.question div {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.answer {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="icons">[+]</div>
  <div>
    Question
  </div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
  ANSWER
  <br>ANSWER
  <br>ANSWER
  <br>ANSWER
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="icons">[+]</div>
  <div>
    Question
  </div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
  ANSWER
  <br>ANSWER
  <br>ANSWER
  <br>ANSWER
</div>
```